# Where can i find the source code for nfsd syscall for "__NR_nfsservctl(180)"?

Tags: c, unix, linux-kernel, rpc, nfs

I'm not working on a project build based on nfsd recently. And I've found nfsd source code from nfs-utils source-code package, where nfsd main program end with a syscall below, where __NR_nfsctl is 180("#define __NR_nfsservctl 180" defined in unistd_64.h).

```
int
nfsctl (int cmd, struct nfsctl_arg * argp, union nfsctl_res * resp)
{
#ifdef __NR_nfsctl
  return syscall (__NR_nfsctl, cmd, argp, resp);
#else
  errno = ENOSYS;
  return -1;
#endif
}
```

Obviously, the nfsd or /usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd only works as a launcher for real nfs-server serivce. The main functions already exist in linux kernel and only take effect after installing nfs-kernel-server.

I've tried to find the definition for nfsservctl function in the latest linux kernel source. But what I got is only the definition for the system call number in "/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl":

```
177 64  get_kernel_syms
178 64  query_module
179 common  quotactl        sys_quotactl
180 64  nfsservctl
181 common  getpmsg
182 common  putpmsg
183 common  afs_syscall
184 common  tuxcall
185 common  security
186 common  gettid          sys_gettid
187 common  readahead       sys_readahead
```

It's interesting that no syscall function is bound to the nfsservctl syscall number. Is it possible that there is a way to register syscall function dynamically in the linux runtime?

I've also found some source code in /fs/nfsd in linux-kernel source. It's quite possible that the source code for nfsservctl syscall is just defined here. But i cann't locate the entry to the system call.

```
user@node2:~/rpc_test/linux-5.4.251/fs/nfsd$ ls
acl.h              export.c             idmap.h     nfs3xdr.c       nfs4xdr.c   nfsxdr.c  vfs.h
auth.c             export.h             Kconfig     nfs4acl.c       nfscache.c  pnfs.h    xdr3.h
auth.h             fault_inject.c       lockd.c     nfs4callback.c  nfsctl.c    state.h   xdr4cb.h
blocklayout.c      filecache.c          Makefile    nfs4idmap.c     nfsd.h      stats.c   xdr4.h
blocklayoutxdr.c   filecache.h          netns.h     nfs4layouts.c   nfsfh.c     stats.h   xdr.h
blocklayoutxdr.h   flexfilelayout.c     nfs2acl.c   nfs4proc.c      nfsfh.h     trace.c
cache.h            flexfilelayoutxdr.c  nfs3acl.c   nfs4recover.c   nfsproc.c   trace.h
current_stateid.h  flexfilelayoutxdr.h  nfs3proc.c  nfs4state.c     nfssvc.c    vfs.c
```

Could anyone help or provide some hints?

Comment: Yes, the action requested via a call to `syscall()` is performed by the kernel, so the source will be found among the kernel sources.  Possibly, somewhere in here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/fs/nfs. But do you *really* need the sources?  Studying the kernel sources to figure out kernel behavior is pretty much the nuclear option for an application developer.  How about starting by reading its *documentation*, probably [`nfsservctl`(`2`)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nfsservctl.2.html)?

Comment: In fact, note well that the linked manpage says: "Since Linux 3.1, this system call no longer exists.  It has been replaced by a set of files in the nfsd filesystem; see      nfsd(7)."  So if you're looking at a more recent kernel than that (and you probably are) then the actual answer to the title question is "nowhere".

Comment: After searching in the latest linux kernel resource, i failed to find the system call function. But i did find the definition for this system call. In fact, I'm only interested in the source code for nfsd service in linux kernel while i'm not trying to understand linux kernel. I will attach some of my recent progress in the question later. Thanks for the suggestion @JohnBollinger.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel NFS server is a very old piece of code.  As you found, old versions of `nfs-utils/support/nfs/nfsctl.c` define `__NR_nfsctl`.

```
/* compatibility hack... */
#if !defined(__NR_nfsctl) && defined(__NR_nfsservctl)
#define __NR_nfsctl __NR_nfsservctl
#endif
```

`__NR_nfsctl` was the original syscall symbol.  It dates back to the earliest NFS server-related commits to the kernel and was changed to `__NR_nfsservctl` in 1997!  Here's one of the patches that changed it, this one for SPARC: https://ftp.csc.fi/index/Linux/kernel/v2.1/patch-html/patch-2.1.36/linux_include_asm-sparc64_unistd.h.html

As for the kernel (as John Bollinger pointed out in the comments) this syscall has been gone since Linux 3.1, nearly 12 years ago.  To find it, you'll need to check out an earlier version.  Here's where it's bound in Linux 2.6.32, in `include/asm-generic/unistd.h`.

```
#define __NR_nfsservctl 42
__SYSCALL(__NR_nfsservctl, sys_nfsservctl)
```

It's defined at the bottom of `fs/nfsctl.c`.

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(nfsservctl, int, cmd, struct nfsctl_arg __user *, arg,
        void __user *, res)
```

Having said all this, I suspect you may have been thrown off by the extremely old nfs-utils source on github.  It's still under very active development, but the source isn't on github, it's at http://git.linux-nfs.org/?p=steved/nfs-utils.git.  If you read the source that's there, you won't find any mention of the syscall interface.